# What information contains in gap between method table and method body in java bytecode

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, bytecode, decompiling

I'm trying to figure out structure of java bytecode. and till the method table it all flows as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file but after that, there is a huge gap between method body (which I found by passing hex codes for decompiled method instructions)

```
.....00 0300 0400 0000 00[00 02] - method count 
[00 0100 0500 0600 0100 0700 0000 2f00 0100 0100 0000 05] - unexplainable gap 
[2a b700 01b1] - method body
method body is
Code:
   Stack=1, Locals=1, Args_size=1
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return
```

the same thing goes before second method (not the same byte string, but gap with byte sequence)
Also after the method table there is attribute count and attribute table, which I can't interpret too (in wiki there is no structure definition on this block).

```
...[00 0000 02] - attribute count
00 0800 0000 0e00 0300 0000 0500 0400 0600 0700 0700 0900 0000 2000 0300 0000 0b00 0a00 0b00 0000 0400 0700 0e00 0f00 0100 0700 0400 1000 0f00 0200 0100 1100 0000 0200 12
```

Could you provide any resources to figure out this details?

the source code is simple

```
package ru.javamining.decompile;

public class ClassA {
    public int localStackTest(){
        int intVar=1500;
        int intVar1 = 198765;
        return intVar + intVar1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.6). A `method_info` contains a lot more than just code.